How to setup De-Serializer for Kafka Streams Application when message was produced in .NET and has type Confluent.Kafka.Message<TKey, TValue>
I am producing a message to a topic "ITEM_PRICES" using dontnet(Confluent.kafka) library). This Message is meant to be a Key,Value pair with the Key as a string and value as float. I setup the producer serializers as follows:
_producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, float>(producerConfig)
            .SetKeySerializer(Serializers.Utf8)
            .SetValueSerializer(Serializers.Single)
            .Build();

And then produce to the topic like this :
_producer.Produce(ITEM_PRICES, new Confluent.Kafka.Message<string, float> { Key= "ITEMNAME", Value = Convert.ToSingle(itemPrice)});

I need to consume the these messages in my kafka streams application(java) and attempt to do so like this:
KStream<String, Float> itemPriceStream = streamsBuilder
       .stream("ITEM_PRICES", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Float()));
       itemPriceStream .peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value));

But I get this error : Size of data received by Deserializer is not 4.
My question is do I need to create a custom deserializer in order to read these messages into my stream? How would I do that?
I tried deserializing with built in String and Float deserializers and it did not work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I am not familiar with .NET, but seems you write the value as String (not as Float)? -> SetValueSerializer(Serializers.Single)
